# winston logger 2 to 3 upgrade. comma separated messages no longer concatenate

Tags: winston

I am trying to upgrade from winston 2 to 3 due to a problem with stringifying mongoose nested objects. It caused a recursive call, and crashed... (I will open an issue later for winston2).  instead of changing my code everywhere to stringify, I tried upgrading winston. This fixed the problem and it prints successfully. however, my code also contains places where code such as this exists
logger.info("got some object like so", { some object })
this no longer works in winston 3. it only prints the first part.

winston2 code example:

```
const winston = require('winston');


// logger configuration
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level:'info',
      handleExceptions: false,
      json: false,
      colorize: true,
      prettyPrint: true
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});



logger.info('test1',{'test':'test2'}, 'test3?');
```

output is:

```
info: test1 { test: 'test2' } test3?
```

as expected

winston3 code:

```
const winston = require('winston');


const prettyJson = winston.format.printf(info => {
  if (info.message.constructor === Object) {
    info.message = JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)
  }
  console.log(info)
  return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
});

var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports:[
        // transport that prints logs into the console
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'info',
      format: winston.format.combine(
          // winston.format.timestamp(),
          // winston.format.colorize(),
          // winston.format.prettyPrint(),
          // winston.format.splat(),
        winston.format.simple(),

          // prettyJson
      )
    })
    ]
});


logger.info('test1',{'test':'test2'}, 'test3?');
```

output: `info: test1 {"test":"test2"}`

no matter what i try, i cannot repeat the same output of winston2.

Answer (score 0):

```
winston.createLogger({
transports: [
    transportInfo,
],
exceptionHandlers: [
    transportError,
],
rejectionHandlers: [
    transportRejections,
],
exitOnError: false,

format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp({
        format: 'HH:mm:ss.SSS',
    }),
    winston.format.printf((info) => {
        let meta = ''
        let symbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(info)
        if (symbols.length == 2) {
            meta = JSON.stringify(info[symbols[1]])

        }
        return `${info.timestamp} ${[info.level.toUpperCase()]}: ${info.message} ${meta}`;        
    })
)})
```

so code:

```
logger.log('ret')
logger.log('test', 'a', {
    a: 9
}, [4, 5])
```

result to

```
11:57:10.739 INFO: ret 
11:57:10.741 INFO: test ["a",{"a":9},[4,5]]
```